error MSB3095: Invalid argument. The path is not of a legal form
While Building the solution in VB.NET it is throwing below error.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3017,5): error MSB3095: Invalid argument. The path is not of a legal form.

Can anyone will help me on this. Have receive this error very suddenly because i haven't done any changes in the code. The error list doesn't show the line number as well where the exact error is caused.
I tried to updated all the reference files and also looked for solution over the internet but unable to solve the issue.

Try the Clean Solution option.

Is this a problem with a specific project, Winform, XAML form or the like? Is there a recent change to a path referenced in a project? (This could include a change to references.) There was a past question on debugging problem in design mode
